# Two different analytics conflict

Tags: google-analytics

I have been looking for a while before coming to ask here, because I know this topic has already been covered. I needed to put two different analytics on the same website, so I inserted this code before the closing head tag of every page on my website. I found a solution that seemed to work, by creating two different trackers and sending them separately. But the results don't match : the first tracker shows 70 visits, whereas the second one shows 800, and I set both at the same moment.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-40380819-3', 'auto',{'name': 'tracker1'});
ga('tracker1.send', 'pageview');


(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-64657532-1', 'auto',{'name': 'tracker2'});
ga('tracker2.send', 'pageview');
```

What am I doing wrong here ? If there is a better solution I am opened to it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

## Load library only once time!

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-40380819-3', 'auto',{'name': 'tracker1'});
ga('tracker1.send', 'pageview');


ga('create', 'UA-64657532-1', 'auto',{'name': 'tracker2'});
ga('tracker2.send', 'pageview');
```

## Explanation

70 visits from first tracker are there because first async loader is faster than second one and it fires pageview before second tracker overwrites first one. That 800 visits should be almost correct.

Comment: Thanks, that looks fairly obvious now to be honest. I will keep track of results and tell you if it worked.

Comment: Hello. I come back to you after checking the results and comparing them. They are still different with the same gap (60 visits on one day for one, 3 for the other).
I put the code exactly as you typed it before the closing head tag of my website on every page. Any clue ?

Comment: Position of the code is not too important. If you are still facing this issue, make sure you really do not have the (i s o g r a m) code twice in your code. Check what tracker have more visits and then try to find duplicity.